# Quelle est l'intention impliquée par l'orthographe "monste" ?

Tags: sens, lexique

Bonjour,

Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois*, le narrateur décrit les effets provoqués par le cinéma sur les lecteurs :

> Minotaure des Antres ! qui c'est qui nous bouffe nos lecteurs ? qui
> nous l'enveloppe, pompe, déglutit ? Tout-Film ! Déjà les
> hebdomadaires, ces **monstes** des kiosques, nous demi-dévoraient
> vachement les badauds songeux, Tout-Film achève !

À votre avis, ce "*monste*" ne peut être qu'une déformation de *monstre* ? Quel parti peut tirer l'auteur de la suppression d'une seule lettre ici ?

Comment: On peut pas exclure les fautes !

Comment: @LukeSawczak Oui, c'est vrai ! Mais avec cet auteur, on ne sait jamais.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, ça ne peut guère signifier autre chose que *monstres*. Difficile de de savoir si c'est une coquille ou l'intention de l'auteur mais cette graphie ne semble pas avoir été modifiée lors de rééditions.

Si elle est intentionnelle, elle peut évoquer un défaut de prononciation ou une prononciation enfantine.

[image]

Véronique David-Martin, *Les Maîtres de l'orage*, 2012

Comment: Peut-être un cou[p] tordu : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/monstrer mon***s***trer ->  *ces montres* des kiosques (ils affichent des pendules) ||  mon***s***trer -> mon**s**te (ce que montre les kiosques au-delà de l'image elle-même). CasPileÔTraqueThé une CaleVieScie est un art OulipoÉtTique !

Comment: @Personne Comme l'a écrit Ovide: *avec cet auteur, on ne sait jamais* ;-)